# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at plus (js.js:52)

Tags: javascript

Id dind't work ! The javascript said that Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at plus (js.js:52)

```js
var count = 1;
var countEl = document.getElementById("count");

function plus() {
  count++;
  countEl.value = count;
}

function minus() {
  if (count > 1) {
    count--;
    countEl.value = count;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="input_div">
  <input type="text" size="25" value="1" id="count">
  <input type="button" value="-" id="moins" onclick="minus()">
  <input type="button" value="+" id="plus" onclick="plus()">
</div>
```

```
     <div class="col-md-3 py-5">
      <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle">
      <i class="fas fa fa-minus" onclick="minus()"></i></button>
      <input type="text" id="count" value="<?php echo $pro_quantity?>" class="form-control w-25 d-inline">
      <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle">
      <i id="plus" class="fas fa fa-plus" onclick="plus()"></i></button>
     </div>
```

Comment: Has the page loaded when you call `document.getElementById()`?

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code

Comment: when you apply the "<script>" tag in html be sure it is under(after) the html elements

Comment: it works in this stack Overflow, but in my Phpstorm, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you are not loading your script as `<script src="yourfile.js" defer></script>`, with that `defer` attribute in place.

If not, add that to your HTML, because your code is querying the DOM, and so you only want to do that *after the DOM has been created*. The `defer` attribute [guarantees that will be the case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer).

Comment: Yeah it works, but js only used to one element . There are some codes I uploaded @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans

Comment: I don't know what you updated the question with, but it's show two _different_ pieces of code. This answer is for your original code, if you have a new question based on that now working, that's literally _a new question_ rather than something to slip into this one. First see what this new knowledge lets you do because you're back to step one now: [trying to do things yourself, and searching and researching if that doesn't work](/help/how-to-ask).